# html5 onclick update table data

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table that has js to allow me to sort the data. But I need to be able to change the data and have js still sort it when I click the header. I have a input box off to the side with a button. I am looking for a onclick way to change the table data from X to what is ever in that input box.

```html
<td id="tabledata1">
  1
</td>
```

I need to be able to change the "1" in that table data. I can not find the function code to effect that specific number. I am guessing it is something like this `document.getElementById("tabledata1").style.color` but instead of `style.color` there is something to reference table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like this

```js
var cell = document.getElementById("tabledata1");
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
var input = document.getElementById("my-input");
var par = document.getElementById("result");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  cell.textContent = input.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="my-input" type="text" />

<button id="my-button">Change Table Data</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="tabledata1">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Breakdown

First query the document for the ids you want and store them into variables. You can then listen for the click event with the `addEventListener` function.

You can change the text of the table cell, by using the `textContent` property and setting it equal to the value of the input element.